# Can Python Desktop Application Receive Push Notification from Firebase FCM?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, wxpython

I am fairly new to Firebase application development. But one thing that interesting to me about Firebase is the FCM part: that is, with it, we can get our application to receive push notification from server.

Unfortunately, [based on the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging?hl=en), it seems like there is not clear way for a Python desktop application (using WxPython that is), to be able to subscribe to this mechanism. Only web/android/ios are implemented.

Can this be done in a Python desktop application, such as WxPython?

Comment: Does this help? https://pypi.org/project/firebase/

Comment: Checking on that! Thanks!